# From DataGridView to StringBuilder obj

Tags: c#, datagridview, stringbuilder

I have a DataGridView (dgv1) with some data loaded into it.  I'd like to loop through dgv1 and append the data from specific columns (0,1,3 and 4) to a StringBuilder object (sb).  I envisioned it would look something like this:

```
        // Add data to the StringBuilder
        int currentRow = 0;
        StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv1.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in dgv1.Columns)
            {
                temp.Append(dataGridView2.Rows[currentRow].Cells[col].Value.ToString());
                currentRow++;
            }
        }
```

However, I don't think this is quite right.  Can someone offer some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think it's not right, honestly.

One thing that I can think about is actually, if you use a DataBinding to bind to DataGrid, iterate over data binded values and not UI control content.  In this case you potentially can use LINQ, which will lead to more clear code....

Regards.

Comment: That's a good idea.  Instead of going against the control, I can just go against its data source.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you do not need this:

```
dataGridView2.Rows[currentRow]
```

because the same object is already here:

```
dgr
```

in this way using directly `dgr` as you should, you simplify getting rid of `currentRow`

Comment: And of course as Tigran said, would be better to iterate directly versus the DataSource instead of using the UI Control... :)